# Limit height of a view to the height of the parent view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scroll layout with a relative layout in each line. Now is there an image and a text, and I want to limit the height of each line to the text.

So if my image is higher than the text, that the image will be resized to the height of the text (proportional). How can I do this in XML?

At the moment the line definition looks like (copied from the mumble android implementation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userRowState"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userRowStatus"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[Name]"
        android:id="@+id/userRowName"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userRowState" />
    <!--
        singleLine is deprecated but it is the only way to get ellipsize work
        it seems. 'inputType text, maxLines 1' didn't work. It's a known issue
        that Google has been unable to reproduce in 1½ years
        http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882 Will see what
        happens first, they remove support for singleLine or they manage to
        reproduce the error. :p
    -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sincerely xZise

Comment: This is a good question. Offhand, I can't think of a way you could do this in an XML layout, although it seems like it would be fairly easy to do programmatically. I wonder if you could just use a ViewStub instead of the ImageView, then in your onCreate method, just inflate them as needed, passing the TextView's height as the LayoutParams for the ImageView? From there, you could just adjust your ImageView's scaleType as needed.

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way. Why don't you set layout_height of the parent item in your case the relative layout and use fill_parent in your child items.

Answer (score 0):

You could try aligning the top and bottom of the icon to the top and bottom of the userRowName:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userRowState"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/userRowName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userRowName"/>
```

This should make it decrease in size when the text decreases. It will remain centered horizontally on its old position though and it won't grow as it's limited in horizontal direction.